# ¿Cómo hago para que la flecha de regresar en el action bar de Android Studio funcione?

Tags: android-studio, actionbar

Tengo el siguiente código y la flecha se visualiza sin embargo al presionarla no hace nada, los demás botones funcionan:

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_salary, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
        when (item!!.itemId) {
            R.id.home -> {
                sharePreferences(this, "calculos").clearPreferences()
                finish()
            }
            R.id.btnOk -> {
                if (calcAverageSalary() > 0) {
                    finish()
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "El total acumulado no puede ser 0", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }
            R.id.btnComplete -> {
                if (!item.isChecked) {
                    item.isChecked = true
                    completeAll(salary1, comission1, total1, true)
                    completeAll(salary2, comission2, total2, true)
                    completeAll(salary3, comission3, total3, true)
                    completeAll(salary4, comission4, total4, true)
                    completeAll(salary5, comission5, total5, true)
                    completeAll(salary6, comission6, total6, true)
                    completeAll(salary7, comission7, total7, true)
                    completeAll(salary8, comission8, total8, true)
                    completeAll(salary9, comission9, total9, true)
                    completeAll(salary10, comission10, total10, true)
                    completeAll(salary11, comission11, total11, true)
                    completeAll(salary12, comission12, total12, true)
                } else {
                    item.isChecked = false
                    completeAll(salary2, comission2, total2, false)
                    completeAll(salary3, comission3, total3, false)
                    completeAll(salary4, comission4, total4, false)
                    completeAll(salary5, comission5, total5, false)
                    completeAll(salary6, comission6, total6, false)
                    completeAll(salary7, comission7, total7, false)
                    completeAll(salary8, comission8, total8, false)
                    completeAll(salary9, comission9, total9, false)
                    completeAll(salary10, comission10, total10, false)
                    completeAll(salary11, comission11, total11, false)
                    completeAll(salary12, comission12, total12, false)
                }
            }
        }
        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar editando tu Manifest:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".Activity2"          
        android:parentActivityName=".Activity1" />
```

Lo que estas haciendo es decirle cual sera la activity donde quieres regresar al presionar el icono de la flecha

Comment: Hola y gracias por tu respuesta, ya probé con eso y no me funcionó. Cabe recalcar que quiero regresar de un Activity a un Fragment.

Comment: Es que al presionar el botón de back no reconoce nada del código que se está enviando.